# Ubuntu tty1, can't get into the desktop

Tags: startup, python3

When I start the OS this is what I get after I login in (see the pic). I can't get into the desktop. I think the problem started when I uninstall python3 but I couldnt find any solution. I'm using a virtual machine, but I dont wanna loose my files. Any help would be usefull.
[This is what I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jv0dt.png)

[This is the installation type](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z97O5.png)

Comment: Do you want to learn how to fix it? Or do you want it fixed as quickly as possible?

Comment: I'm pretty new on Ubuntu so for now I would choose the quickly way. And I need those files like right now ahah. Thanks for the respond by the way.

Comment: Quick: 1. Get out your LiveUSB installer (or use a friend's machine to make a new one). 2. Use the "Try Ubuntu" environment to back up your data. 3. Re-install Ubuntu. Total time: A bit over an hour, plus backup time. Lesson: NEVER remove or change the system-provided Python3. Your system needs it.

Comment: Your picture shows you logged in, so you can look around right now & copy (`cp`, `scp` etc) the files off the machine right now...) though if I have problems, I tend to use *live* media too to explore (and avoid risking making a issue worst, at least until I've worked out what the issue is).  FYI:  As many Ubuntu system tools rely on `python3`, after it is removed they won't be usable (which includes many functions, esp. noticed next login/reboot.  [non-GUI] Terminal commands will work though as they don't rely on `python3`

Comment: @guiverc yeah, the files are there I saw them using cd and ls comands but I dont know how  to copy the files off the machine using the terminal (I used to do it moving the folder from the machine to my actual system). And no, it doesn't work that post for me, I've already checked it after I posted this

Comment: @user535733 Does reinstalling keep my files?

Comment: You need to reverse whatever you did (and the consequences of your action).  Your apt logs will tell you (`/var/log/apt/history.log` as well as your command history).  At a minimum you need to get `python3-minimal | 3.8.2-0ubuntu2   | focal           | amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, ppc64el, riscv64, s390x` installed for some user functions to become available.. and you're limited currently to only tools that don't require python to be funcitoning (ie. `wget` to download & `dpkg` to install... many front-end tools won't be available).  A re-install is usually faster if you're a newbie.

Comment: A reinstall might keep your files; might not. Depends upon if you make the right choices. That's why backing up your data before a reinstall before is wise. Maybe you will make a typo or a wrong choice.

Comment: You can re-install without losing files, or you can re-install & lose everything... You decide the outcome by what options you select.  I'd suggest 'something-else', selecting your existing partition(s) and for sure do **NOT** format any... It'll cause system directories to be wiped, but no user directory is touched (unless you format)... Some server apps do keep config files in system dirs (that are wiped) so that's data that will need restoration, but desktop apps do not do that.. but adjust for whatever apps you had installed/were using (ie. backup first is always safest!)

Comment: @guiverc So now I'm on the installation types, what should I do next? I uploaded a pic so you can see clearly what I'm doing. the files are where the system was installed

Comment: So I was able to move the folders to a shared folder I had and then I just installed Ubuntu from zero. So thanks both of you, you helped me a lot in this trouble. Lesson learned, that's for sure.